# cocos2dx how to clear CCAnimationCache

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

In cocos2d-x, I cache the animation in CCAnimationCache. But how can I clear all the animation-cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
CCAnimationCache::sharedAnimationCache()->purgeSharedAnimationCache();
```

It releases all the CCAnimation objects and the shared instance.
Else you can also use

```
removeAnimationByName("youAnimationName");
```

this will remove particular animation you wish.

Hope this helps you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d, we use these calls...find same api in cocos2d-x

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures];
[CCTextureCache purgeSharedTextureCache];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
[CCSpriteFrameCache purgeSharedSpriteFrameCache];
```